# Get rid of columns that do not have headers

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read in a CSV file that has columns without headers. Currently, my solution is

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df = df[[col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed' not in col]]
```

This seems a little hacky, and would fail if the file contains columns with the word 'Unnamed' in them. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think this is already a quite good solution. If you want to make it slightly more robust, then you could still replace the `if 'Unnamed' not in col` with `if not col.startswith('Unnamed: ')`.

Answer (score 2):

The `usecols` argument of the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function accepts a callable function as input. If you provide a function that evaluates to `False` for your undesired column headers, then these columns are dropped.

```
func = lambda x: not x.startswith('Unnamed: ')
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=func)
```

I guess that this solution is not really fundamentally different from your original solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could rename those columns first?

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^Unnamed:.*', '')    
df[[col for col in df.columns if col]]
```

Still pretty hacky, but at least this replaces only the strings which start with "Unnamed:" with '' before filtering them.